# Cisco same vlan user and server (Packet tracer)

Tags: cisco, vlan

Accounts server and Accounts PC are in the Same VLAN

Is possible that I only allow FTP and HTTP access from Accounts to Accounts server. Other protocols must be denied.

Or do I need to create another vlan for the Accounts server then Configure Inter-vlan routing then create an ACL for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a Vlan Access List to filter traffic within the vlan.  Here is a good example of how to do so:

https://networklessons.com/cisco/vlan-access-list-vacl/

However if it was me i'd move the server to a new subnet/vlan and use ip access lists.

Also depending on the server windows/linux you can configure the server's firewall to only allow connections on the desired ports.